# Substring alternative to consider null values in sql

Tags: sql, string, oracle, sql-update, substring

I have my update statement in Oracle SQL where I concatenate N after my 9th byte of MISC_FLAGS

```
UPDATE SYS_CODE 
SET MISC_FLAGS = SUBSTR(MISC_FLAGS, 1, 9) || 'N', 
    mod_date_time = sysdate, 
    user_id = 'Feature Number'  
WHERE REC_TYPE = 'X' 
  AND CODE_TYPE = 'XXX' 
  AND CODE_ID = 'XXXX';
```

But in some cases we have example 8th and 9th byte in Misc Flag set as null. Substring in those cases does not consider 8th and 9th byte and updates 8th byte to N instead of 10th.

Does anyone have an alternative for this?

Comment: Then you should consider and tell us what character you want in the 8th and 9th position.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want `RPAD()`:

```
MISC_FLAGS = RPAD(SUBSTR(MISC_FLAGS, 1, 9), 9, ' ') || 'N'
```

This adds blank characters to `MISC_FLAGS` if it has less than 9 characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RPAD()`. For example:

```
UPDATE SYS_CODE SET
  MISC_FLAGS = RPAD(SUBSTR(MISC_FLAGS,1,9), 9, ' ') || 'N', 
  mod_date_time = sysdate, 
  user_id = 'Feature Number'  
WHERE REC_TYPE = 'X' AND CODE_TYPE= 'XXX' AND CODE_ID = 'XXXX';
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel a combination of RPAD --> SUBSTR in below fashion must help you.

Here is a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a039c95eb9bd3e06f38040b46e3f41ac) for your help.

```
UPDATE SYS_CODE SET
  MISC_FLAGS = SUBSTR(RPAD(MISC_FLAGS, 9, '0'),1,9)|| 'N', 
  mod_date_time = sysdate, 
  user_id = 'Feature Number'  
WHERE REC_TYPE = 'X' AND CODE_TYPE= 'XXX' AND CODE_ID = 'XXXX';
```